# SQL Query on a Table with Geography Column to Find If There Is Any Row That is Within a Certain Distance From Any Other Row In The Same Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with multiple rows. The table has a non null geography type column.

Lets say I have a table with the following columns: ID, Latitude, Longitude, GeoData. GeoData column is of geography type in SQL Server 2016.

I know how to find rows within a certain distance from a single point.

What I am struggling with is to write a query that will compare all rows against every other row excluding itself *.ID <> *.ID

I have something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM GeoTable tableA 
INNER JOIN GeoTable tableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID 
WHERE tableA.GeoData.STDistance(tableB.GeoData) <= 500 AND tableA.ID <> 
tableB.ID
```

But it is not doing what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the results I was looking for.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT
  tableA.*,
  tableB.*,
  tableA.GeoData.STDistance(tableB.GeoData) AS DistanceApart
FROM GeoTable tableA
JOIN GeoTable tableB
ON (tableA.GeoData.STDistance(tableB.GeoData) <= 500) AND tableA.ID <> tableB.ID ORDER BY DistanceApart
```

However, answer given by @BWarner also achieves the same results, which is exactly what I wanted, so thank you!

Out of curiosity, how can one improve performance of this query?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need a cross join. This creates a Cartesian product between the two tables. You can read about it [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx). The performance isn't very good if the table is very large. Is this an issue for you?

```
SELECT * FROM GeoTable tableA 
OUTER APPLY GeoTable tableB
WHERE tableA.GeoData.STDistance(tableB.GeoData) <= 500 AND tableA.ID <> tableB.ID
```

Let me know if this doesn't do what you want, and we can work to improve it.